# Can I create a switch instruct and assign the default BasicBlock later?

Tags: llvm, llvm-c++-api

the API of creating a switch instruct(

```
SwitchInst *CreateSwitch(Value *V, BasicBlock *Dest, unsigned NumCases = 10,
                           MDNode *BranchWeights = nullptr,
                           MDNode *Unpredictable = nullptr)
```

) needs a default BasicBlock, but in my code, due to the design, I cannot get default BasicBlock when creating, and usually, default case is written as the last statement in a switch statement, so can I create a switch instruct and assign the default BasicBlock later?

Answer (score 2):

Pass nullptr to the `Create()` function to get a SwitchInst object and use `SwitchInst::setDefaultDest()` later.